# XOR gate with NAND

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I am attempting to build an XOR gate with NAND ICs. This schematic

[image]

is how I am wiring up the IC (I know the schematic is a little confusing but I tried to construct it best I can).

I am attempting to recreate this logic circuit: http://i42.tinypic.com/n4weo6.jpg

Data sheet for CD4011B IC: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4011b.pdf

It is not operating as expected, the LED is always on when I expect it to be off by default, off when both switches are pressed and only on when one or the other switch is pressed.

Have I wired this circuit incorrectly? Can anybody tell me where I have gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: A proper schematic with gates would be much easier to follow.

Comment: The link is not accessble: 'remote linking not available'

Comment: Sorry, please see image here: http://i42.tinypic.com/n4weo6.jpg

Comment: Provide a *real* schematic. -1 and voting to close in the mean time.

Comment: I'm new to electronics, I'm really only seeking help on what should be an easy to solve situation for someone with more experience than me. Why should it be closed because I'm unable to construct a 'real' schematic?

Comment: I've added a schematic derived from the wiring diagram

Comment: @JacobClark Have you double checked whether you wired it correctly in practice? The diagram you drew looks fine, but maybe you made a mistake when actually building it on your protoboard.

Comment: Would benefit from a current limiting resistor 470 ohm to the LED.

Comment: *"Why should it be closed because I'm unable to construct a 'real' schematic?"* - Because 1) doing so helps you understand your circuit. 2) one person doing so (you) is better than ten people doing so in their heads (readers) 3) It makes it easier for people to help you (so more will try) 4) it makes you look like you have actually made an effort and might read an answer. 5) It's etiquette - like saying please and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit looks fine

The XOR table should be

```
                          A     B          Q
                          0     0          0         
                          0     1          1 
                          1     0          1 
                          1     1          0
```

Comment: Strange as the LED is always on! Thanks so much for your reply though, it may be a faulty IC.

Comment: @JacobClark Make yourself a simple logic probe to test around the circuit - 470R resistor with LED in series (or use a voltmeter). Connect the LED cathode to ground and test the pins of the IC. Start with the first gate and see if the output (pin 3) changes when you operate the switches. Make a note of the truth table. Then try pin 11 and then pin 10. Work your way through the circuit and follow the signal. It may simply be a bad connection somewhere.